# Help me decide if this opamp circuit will work as purposed

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, bjt, circuit-design

please help me decide if this will work:

Primary objective: Amplify 0~3v input signal to 0~12V output signal.

[image]

I understand that this whole setup is a bit unusual, since I can simply connect the +input of opamp to 12VDC, and with my resistors' values, 3v input could be amplified to 12V (I'm 80% sure). But nevertheless I want to know if this odd scheme will work? I think I'll have to be very careful with my OpAmp output, which dictates the 3904?

Edit: **My most sincere apologies there SHOULD BE a pullup resister between the collector and the 12V**, for some reason this slipped through my double check, incredible, I'm new to eagle and the copy paste in it isn't that intuitive.

The resistor has a value of 2K.

Edit #2:

Sorry for the delay but a few things to clarify, apologize again if I overlooked your question, there are too many and I'm kind of really busy:

1. 200mA is supposed to be the current drawing in. This whole setup is kind of to sink current from lower-tier components that will be connected to this interface, so 12v/2K = 6ma isn't what I'm talking about.
2. The resistor should be 90k/30k, as some of yous suggested, my mistake.
3. Oscillation: I believe your concerns are quite legit but please be advised  that the input will be mostly "static" voltage signals, meaning it rarely changes more frequently than 5 times per second, so I'm skeptical that it will be that huge of a problem, I could very well be very, very wrong.

   - Matt

Comment: It is not clear what you are doing.  Do you have a +12 volt power supply?

Comment: @PeterBennett Hello, yes I do, as shown in the diagram? Is it properly displayed?

Comment: It won't do anything at all useful. The output will always be +12 unless the power supply loses the fight destroying Q4.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Gah! You are right, I can't believe the circuit was shorted to begin with. Really silly question I guess.

Comment: Google "single supply noninverting amplifier". You will need to supply the opamp with >12V (e.g. 15V).

Comment: It definitely will oscillate or latch with positive feedback

Comment: Just use a 12V op amp non-inverting amplifier with resistor ratio 3:1 to get a gain of +4. There are many problems with your general approach, not the least of which will be compensation to prevent oscillation, since you are intending to add gain.

Comment: It is important to write better specs before presenting a design.  What load, current and BW?  This transistor pull down only sinks current and needs a pullup R and Vin+- reversed, but will be less stable (due to added GBW phase shift) than opamp which can drive 600 Ohms

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I'm *hoping* that positive feedback was a "schematic oops" from the OP. Assuming it was, and he meant the feedback to be into the inverting input, with "INPUT1" hitting the non-inverting input, then simply powering the Op Amp from a >=12.5V rail should make all the rest of the circuit superfluous (i.e. use the OpAmp, R1 & R2...the rest is all waste.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 assuming the transitor has a resistor to +12V  it inverts the output of the op-amp so over-all the feedback is negative, and but for C2 the circuit should be well-behaved..

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 , sorry about the unclear specs as I'm in the dark as well, since this is a part of an experimental project, But it's safe to assume the max current is around 200ma, while BW is of little importance here since it will work well within 5Hz.

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB You are right, all the rest could have been useless, but I intend the feed back to go into the NON-inverting input but the actual input signal i.e. INPUT1 into the inverting input, and hope it can work. As I said, this is an odd, unusual scheme but long story short, some last minute change took place in certain meeting and I have no do minimal modifications on my board to make ends meet... thus this abomination of a circuit.

Comment: @MattCox Please add the caveat about having to reuse most of the existing circuit, the 200ma output requirement, and the <=5Hz GBW to your question post. Makes it easier for us to gove more useful answers if we don't all have to dig through all these comments to find the important bits. -- Also, can we see a diagram of what's already (semi-unchangeably) soldered together, so we can see more easily which pieces can/cannot be easily modified?

Comment: FYI, 12V through a 2k resistor only feeds 6ma when shorted directly to GND...not sure that's a very good place to try to pull 200ma from :(

Comment: Believe it or not I have seen the circuit before .I saw it in 1992 .I was very critical of it .It was in production in a CHCH sweatshop .I felt that it would be difficult to stabilise so should not be built.It was assembled in the thousands with side cutters and thru hole hand soldering .I was also concerned about parts count but no body else was .It seems nuts but it was in the current limiting of a telco rectifier .

Comment: @MattCox  Improve your question with your specs.  200mA is that source or sink, If so what is the real load impedance and voltage. Vcc or 0V?  2k will not always drive 200mA   and you should know hFE drops to 10% of hFE or 1:10 (Ib:Ic) when Vce=Vce(sat)

Comment: The extra gain provided by the transistor will likely cause oscillations, especially when your closed-loop gain is only 3. As @Autistic says, stability would be questionable.

Comment: @glen_geek  how would you approach estimating the added Pole to a given Bode Plot given asymmetric gain assuming hFE=100?  ( just checking if you know)

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I've learned to avoid squirrely circuits. And it'd help to see a proper circuit...is that op-amp supply 3.3V or 33V? Too many gotcha's to pursue. BTW, I think OP wanted closed loop gain of 4. My bad for saying 3.

Answer (score 1):

No, your circuit will not work. The main problem is that 12V is connected directly to Vout. And Q4 is going to short 12V to ground (which will destroy Q4).

Look at this schematic. Just for inspiration.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flAUj2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**UPDATE:**
I changed value of R2 from 120kΩ to 90kΩ. It is wrong in question too. If OP wants to amplify from 0-3V to 0-12V than there should be 1:3 ratio for R1:R2

**UPDATE2 - EXPLANATION:**
This circuit makes Vout = 4* Vin

If you increase Vin, output of U3 will go lower, which will make mosfet M1 more open (Vgs is more negative = Rds is lower) and thus Vout increases. It will increase until voltage at non-inverting input of U3 is equal to inverting input (which is Vin).

If you increase Vin, output of U3 will go higher, which will make mosfet M1 less open (Vgs is less negative = Rds increases) and thus Vout decreases. It will decrease until voltage at non-inverting input of U3 is equal to inverting input (which is Vin).

Comment: Unfortunately, OP stated in comments that most of his proposed circuit is a holdover from a previous revision of a project, and he's *supposed* to reuse it with as little modification as possible...which rules out this option, or my original suggestion to simply use a non-inverting topology to start with.

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB I do not think it is possible to reuse only those components and make working circuit that comply requirements at the same time.

Comment: You switched the inputs of the op-amp..

Comment: @m.Alin no, if you look closely, he jst drew his opAmp in the other orientation...the Vis is still connected to U3's inverting input, and feedback is to the non-inverting.

Comment: @m.Alin I also changed NPN BJT for P-channel mosfet. I think I wired opamp correctly.

Comment: I just read "Amplify 0~3v input signal to 0~12V output signal" in the OP's question and concluded that he needs *negative* feedback on the op-amp; so the feedback should go to the inverting (-) input of the op-amp and the input signal to the non-inverting pin, shouldn't it?

Comment: @m.Alin and another requirement (that OP wrote to comments) is current 200mA. I don't know what are you commenting. I checked my circuit again and it is wired correctly.

Comment: Could you please explain what your circuit is supposed to do?
 Maybe I'm not getting it, but is your circuit intended to amplify something? If yes, it needs negative feedback which you can only get by wiring the output to the *inverting* input, not the non-inverting one, as you did.

Comment: @m.Alin explanation added to answer.

Comment: This works, but I think C2 is too large. It's causing significant distortion even at the 5Hz stated in the question; perhaps try 1μF instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good start, but I see two flaws.

1: your output terminal is connected directly to 12VDC, you probably forgot to draw a resistor between the 12VDC and the transistor. given your choice of 2K for the base resistor, 1K seems about right in this place.

2: C2 between output and ground seems likely to cause trouble (amplifier oscillation). you probably don't want it. or perhaps you want it between 12VDC and ground.

Comment: It doesn't look pretty at all. Output is connected directly to 12V and transistor Q4 is going to short 12V to ground.

Comment: did you read past the first sentence?  I'm assuming that missing resistor is a draughting error, because without it the circuit makes no sense at all.

Comment: So, your first sentence was just ironic?

Comment: The guy's either a beginner or he's "having a bad day" and but for the resistor separating the collector and output from  12V and C2, it looks good to me. he got the resistive divider right, and connected it correctly to the non-inverting, input. even included power supply by-passing capacitors. He's clearly made an effort, and some praise is due.

Comment: If somebody is beginner, he needs honest feedback. Yes, he made pretty good effort. But the result schematic is not good, this is the honest information. Your suggestion to add resistor between 12V and collector doesn't seem good to me, because you don't know what amperage is required and you will not meet the requirements for 0-12V output.

Comment: Ok. I will temper my enthusiasm.

Comment: OK. Downvote removed ;)

Comment: @Jasen et al,  Always expect a load spec before assuming a solution

Answer (score 0):

Your gain is 1+ since you have inverted the feedback the Vin- is now the positive input so Av=1+R2/R1 assuming you use something 1k Pullup and you REALLY NEED the transistor to pull down a charged cap with high current and small pullup current.

This a poor inverting negative peak detector with storage cap and missing pullup resistor with a gain of +5?

Where are the rest of your design specs?